# Read line-delimited data in VB6

Tags: vb6

So I have a number of text files that I'm trying to read with Visual Basic. They all have the same formatting:

```
[number of items in the file]
item 1
item 2
item 3
...etc.
```

What I'm trying to do is declare an array of the size of the integer in the first line, and then read each line into corresponding parts of the array (so item 1 would be array[0], item 2 would be array[1], etc. However, I'm not sure where to start on this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty basic stuff (no pun intended):

```
Dim F As Integer
Dim Count As Integer
Dim Items() As String
Dim I As Integer

F = FreeFile(0)
Open "data.txt" For Input As #F
Input #F, Count
ReDim Items(Count - 1)
For I = 0 To Count - 1
    Line Input #F, Items(I)
Next
Close #F
```

Answer (score 1):

try this for VB6

```
Dim file_id As Integer
Dim strline as string
Dim array_item() as string

'Open file
file_id = FreeFile
Open "C:\list.txt" For Input AS #file_id 

Dim irow As Integer
irow = 0    

'Loop through the file
Do Until EOF(file_id)

    'read a line from a file
    Line Input #file_id, strline

    'Resize the array according to the line read from file
    Redim Preserve array_item(irow)

    'put the line into the array
    array_item(irow) = strline

    'move to the next row
    irow = irow + 1
Loop

Close #file_id
```

Comment: As the OP says the first line gives the count, it can get that first, removing the performance hit of `Redim Preserve`.

Comment: Thanks Deanna, it would be much better.

Answer (score 0):

The VB function you're looking for is "split":

http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_csv_to_array.html

Comment: Erm, good answer, for a different question. No commas. No need to split.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim FullText As String, l() As String
'''Open file for reading using Scripting Runtime. But you can use your methods
Dim FSO As Object, TS As Object
Set FSO = createbject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set TS = createbject("Scripting.TextStream")
Set TS = FSO.OpenTextFile(FilePath)
TS.ReadLine 'Skip your first line. It isn't needed now.
'''Reading the contents to FullText and splitting to the array.
FullText = TS.ReadAll
l = Split(FullText, vbNewLine) '''the main trick
```

Splitting automatically resizes l() and stores all data.
Now the l() array has everything you want.

Comment: Wouldn't it be useful to demonstrate **"Write something, which will copy all the text into FullText variable"**, otherwise this answer doesn't really add anything

Comment: @MattDonnan , OK. Now I've clarified my answer.